# Need to add a reference to a component's render method. addComponentAsRefTo(...)

Tags: reactjs, render

I believe I understand the following error, but I don't fully understand the solution.

> Uncaught Error: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded

```
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap-modal';
//import MyCustomObject from './MyCustomObject';
import ReactTelInput from 'react-telephone-input';

...
render(){
    return (
        <Modal show={this.props.showModal}>
            <Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Title>This is a heading </Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
                    <ReactTelInput
                        defaultCountry="us"
                        flagsImagePath='../../images/flags.png'
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                        onBlur={this.handleInputBlur}
                    /> // was previously <MyCustomObject/>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button onClick={this.props.changeModal}>Close</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    );
 }
```

My understandinng is that since a Modal doesn't recognize MyCustomObject, it has no idea how to render it. So, how can I get around this? Is there a way to directly add MyCustomObject to the Modal object? My next idea was to create my own modal class, extend react-bootstrap-modal, and simply have this extension import from MyCustomObject, but this also didn't work.

So, how can I render my own objects inside of something like react-bootstrap-modal?

Comment: Can you share the code for MyCustomObject?

Comment: Instead, I changed MyCustomOBject to be another NPM object: import ReactTelInput from 'react-telephone-input' (see above).

The same problem persists though. MyCustomObject worked everywhere outside of being in this model. Same goes for ReactTelInput.

Comment: "or you have multiple copies of React loaded". Another approach here is to check if you have some versioning issues in your dependencies. If react is loaded twice, with two different versions loaded at the same time, this might be the error-message you get. Example: if you are running the last version of react, and react-boostrap-modal, which might be running an older version.

Comment: My output looks clean:

+-- babel-preset-react@6.24.1 extraneous
+-- react@15.5.4
+-- react-addons-update@15.5.2 extraneous
+-- react-bootstrap@0.31.0 extraneous
+-- react-bootstrap-modal@3.0.1 extraneous
+-- react-dom@15.5.4
+-- react-fontawesome@1.6.1
+-- react-icons@2.2.3 extraneous
+-- react-places-autocomplete@5.0.0 extraneous
+-- react-select@1.0.0-rc.3 extraneous
+-- react-tabs@0.8.3 extraneous

+-- react-telephone-input@4.0.1 extraneous

+-- react-text-input@0.0.8 extraneous

Comment: Additionally, this modal works without putting anobject inside off the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was hard to figure out because I was using facebook's original method of implementing react. in my index.cshtml file, I had:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remarkable/1.7.1/remarkable.min.js"></script>
```

So, react was loaded once via node module, and once here. This was tricky to figure out since I did technically have react once via node module. loading it in the cshtml was what was ruining me.

So, I also had to add to my webpack.config file in order to load react correctly and removed the scripts from my cshtml.

```
loaders: [
    {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
    }
```